# Given that $P$ projects onto $C(A)$, why does $I - P$ project onto the left nullspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection-matrices

While doing some research to help me on my homework, I read that if $P$ projects onto the column space of $A$, then $I - P$ projects onto the left nullspace.

I'm trying to prove this for my own purposes because I don't understand where this came from. Can anyone help me understand why this is? Thank you!

Comment: The left null space is orthogonal to the column space. Think of an $m \times n$ matrix. The left null space and the column space are $m$-dimensional, whereas the row space and the right null space are $n$-dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

First you I want to remind what it means that $P: V \to V$ is a projection.
$$ P \text{ is a Projection} \Leftrightarrow P^2 = P$$
So you need to check this condition for $I-P$:
$$(I-P)^2 = I^2 - PI -IP - P^2 =I - P - P + P = I-P$$
now you want to check $\ker P = \text{ran} (I-P)$.

- We start with $\subseteq$:

  take $x \in \ker P$ then you know $Px = 0$ and $( I - P)x = x$ which implies that $x \in \text{ran}(I-P)$.
- at last $\supseteq$:

  take $x \in \text{ran}(I-P)$ then you know there is a $y\in V$ with $(I-P)y = x$. if you take the image of $(I-P)$ on both sides you get $$(I-P)^2y = (I-P)x$$ now you can use the characteristic of a projection and you get $$(I-P)y  = (I-P)x \\ x = x - Px \quad| -x\\ 0 = -Px$$ which means nothing else than $x\in\ker P$.

Comment: I'm sorry to inconvenience but I don't know what "ker" and "ran" mean. I don't know if those are like matlab things or just something in math that I have yet to learn, but would you mind explaining? Thank you for answering!

Comment: If $A: V \to W$ is linear a linear mapping then $\ker A := \{x\in V : Ax = 0\}$ you call it nullspace. the range of $A$ is denoted by $\text{ran}\, A := \{y \in W : \exists x\in V \text{ so that } Ax = y\} = A(V)$ the image of $V$ under $A$.

Comment: You should prove range(I-P)=ker$P^T$

Comment: @LawrenceMano Then you need to clarify your definition of $P^{T}$ in this setting. Do you mean the adjoint? Then this follows simply by $P^{T} = P$.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek. Agreed. Thank you.